# Update RecyclerView after Dialog and orientation change

Tags: java, android

I have an app which uses only one activity. Inside, I load a fragment with a recyclerview. 
Each item in the recyclerview is a dialog fragment. The user can change the items, therefore the recyclerview is updated when the dialog is dismissed.

The problem I'm having now is that when the app is rotated while the dialog is active, the recyclerview will not get updated after the dialog is dismissed.

My dialog gets recreated along with everything in the app when destroyed so I suspect the dismisslistener gets destroyed when recreating.

The dialog exposes a method to set the dismisslistener and then overrides the event to check if one was set.

```java
public void setOnDismissListener(DialogInterface.OnDismissListener 
onDismissListener) {
    this.onDismissListener = onDismissListener;
}

@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    if (onDismissListener != null) {
        onDismissListener.onDismiss(dialog);
    }
}
```

I then set a dismisslistener inside the `onViewBindHolder` of the recyclerview

```java
editor.setOnDismissListener(dialog -> {
    recycler.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I'm unsure why this happens, but it seems that after changing the orientation and recreating everything, the recyclerview is never updated. I found out that the method is still called, because inside the ondismisslistener was another function that updated another view with `getView().findViewById()` which then crashed the app because `getView` returned null.

I couldn't find any other post about this here.

Does anyone know how I fix the dismisslistener or maybe any other way to wait for a dialogfragment to close?

Comment: This may be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758213/android-why-dialogfragment-return-nullpointer-on-orientation-change

Comment: Which method are you calling setOnDismissListener(...) from?

Comment: @RafsanjaniYaahWaduudu I'm calling it inside the `onBindViewHolder` method of my recyclerview class.

Comment: @IronMan 
I have taken a look at it, but sadly the answers there dont seem to work for me.

Comment: Can you post more code from your adapter and your recyclerview's activity

Comment: @RafsanjaniYaahWaduudu here is the entire adapter : https://pastebin.com/66BzL7sH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I've found out what went wrong.
When recreated, the dialog loses all his variables, just like everything else.

It could be theoretically possible to save those variables in the bundle and fetch them again on recreation, but I have not found a way to do this with an OnClickListener, since objects passed to a bundle must be serializable or parcable.

Therefore, my dialogues are now just dismissed when they do not have any variables via a check in OnCreate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" to your activity in AndroidManifest?
Otherwise try (onRestoreInstanceState() and onSaveInstanceState()

Comment: Wouldn't that prevent the app from turning?
I want the app to turn. The problem is just that the dismisslistener gets lost.

And could you specify what you mean by "try `onRestoreInstanceState` and `onSaveInstaceState`"? These methods exist, but just overriding them won't do much afaik.